# $\{b\in A:d(a,b)\leq r\}$ is compact set of (A,d)?

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

We suppose that $(A,\overrightarrow {A})$  is an affine Euclidean space and that $d$ is the associated Euclidean distance. We consider $a\in A$ and $r>0$.

***My question*** : can we say that $\{b\in A:d(a,b)\leq r\}$ is compact set of (A,d)?

Comment: What are your thoughts on that question ?

Comment: I am a beginner in Euclidean surveyor. What I think since $\overrightarrow {A}$ is a Euclidean vector space Then closed balls are compact, but can we say that this is true for the Euclidean affine space $A$ with the canonical distance $d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping $f \colon \overrightarrow{A} \to A, \quad v \mapsto a + v$ is an isometry between the the metric spaces $\overrightarrow{A}$ and $A$ which maps the ball $\overline{B}(0,r)$ onto $\overline{B}(a,r)$. Since the first ball is compact, the second ball must be too.